# slds-grid into lightning:card into slds-grid: layout broken

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Given this code:

```
<aura:application description="TestApp" extends="force:slds">
    <div class="slds-container_x-large slds-container_center slds-m-top_large">
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col slds-p-left_small">
                anything here
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-p-left_small">
                <lightning:card title="Distribution" iconName="standard:metrics">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-gutters_small slds-border_left"><!-- I'm expecting this left border inside the card-->
                        <div class="slds-col">
                            <p class="slds-text-heading_small">why this grid doesn't fit</p>
                            <p class="slds-text-heading_large">into the parent padding col (line 7)???</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </lightning:card>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

I got this output:

[image]

My question is: **why the second grid doesn't respect the padding column?**

**Update:**

Ok, the solution is wrap the inner grid into this div:

```
<div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
<!--inner grid here-->
</div>
```

So, my question now is **why???**

Comment: [edit] your question, don't add a comment to your own question :)

Comment: I guess that was not the recommended way mentioned in any documentation. Mixing custom markup with non schematic usage of standard SLDS classes might break in new releases.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered the possibility of the padding being aplpied to the external nodes only?

if that is the case, then maybe you should add padding to the internal div where your column is declared.

```
div class="slds-col" + slds-padding
```